# JAXB add xmlns into element when marshalling java

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

How to add xmlns into Element when marshalling Java Object using JAXB, so the result should be like

```
<R>  
    <A xmlns:p2="test" p2:type="type">
        some value
    </A>
</R>
```

my Java entity class is for example:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class R {

    private String a;

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="A")
    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Tried to add namespace into XmlElement, but the result is not what I expected. Please, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In your example it is the `type` attribute that is namespace qualified.  You would set the `namespace` parameter on the `@XmlAttribute` annotation for it.

**R**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="R")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class R {

    @XmlElement(name="A")
    private A a;

}
```

**A**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class A {

    @XmlAttribute(namespace="test")
    private String type;

    @XmlValue
    private String value;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand how to create them!